# TypeError: Events.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, rest

So i'm working with reactjs but i pretty new in reactjs when i want to called my api with componentdidMount this error keep showing TypeError: Events.map is not a function can someone help me

```
class Rank extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
   this.state = {Events: {}, golfer_events: [] }

}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost/Golfer/api/EventApi/rank?id=2')
    .then(response =>{
            return response.json()   
    })
    .then(json => console.log("json:", json))
    .then(json => this.setState({Events: json.conversation}))

}


render() {
    const {Events} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    Events.map(event =>{
                        const {id, title, golfer} = event;
                        return(
                            <div key ={id}>
                                <Card>
                                    <CardBody>
                                        {title}
                                        {golfer}
                                    </CardBody>
                                </Card>
                            </div>
                            )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In constructor, you are setting Events as object instead of array. Object doesnot have map function causing the issue.

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
       this.state = {Events: [] = [], golfer_events: [] = [] }

    }

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost/Golfer/api/EventApi/rank?id=2')
    .then(response =>{
            return response.json()   
    })
    .then(json => console.log("json:", json))
    .then(json => this.setState({Events: (json.conversation || [])}))

}
```

Comment: like this this.state = { Events: [] }

Comment: but it keeps return TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: initialize it to an empty array = this.state = { Events: [] = [] }

Comment: Your api response might be null, added null check in my answer or your api response might not be an array, can you post your api response?

Comment: {status: "true", message: {…}}
message:
app_desc: "Bangunindo Basic App"
app_favicon_logo: "589acfe2ca996-original.png"
app_id: "1"
app_login_logo: "589acfe7dac68-original.png"
app_mini_logo: "589acfeaeed0c-original.png"
app_single_logo: "589acfde6f070-original.png"
app_title: "Bangunindo"
controller: "Event"
controller_id: 0
controller_name: "EventAPi"
course_holes: (18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
events: {id: "2", golf_course_id: "2", title: "Toraja Charity Golf 2019", date_start: "2019-09-14", date_end: "2019-09-15

Comment: my error not showing again but it's not return anything

Comment: can you console.log(json.conversation) and update the comment rather than full reponse?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing iteration on object using map. map only work on type array. try following.

```
this.state = {Events: [], golfer_events: [] }
```

and make sure you are setting state of event have type array in response.

```
componentDidMount(){
fetch('http://localhost/Golfer/api/EventApi/rank?id=2')
.then(response =>{
        return response.json()   
})
.then(json => console.log("json:", json))
.then(json => this.setState({Events: json.conversation // this value need to be type of array to use map}))

}
```

Comment: it keep show TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: have you check that the value of json.conversation?

Answer (score 1):

you can only use map() function for arrays not for object. array.map() is the syntax. 
componentDidMount will return array then correct the constructor as other answers also mention that

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
   this.state = {Events: [], golfer_events: [] }

}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost/Golfer/api/EventApi/rank?id=2')
    .then(response =>{
            return response.json()   
    })
    .then(json => console.log("json:", json))
    .then(json => this.setState({Events: (json.conversation || [])}))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert Events to array so you can use map()